# QuestPDF have a Previewer option before generating PDF

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, pdf-generation, quest

We have to view PDFs before generating the PDF file. We have tried adding the below-mentioned code but it's not working for us in WinForm and our application gets freezed.

```
using QuestPDF.Fluent;
using QuestPDF.Helpers;
using QuestPDF.Infrastructure;

// code in your main method
var document = Document.Create(container =>
{
    container.Page(page =>
    {
        // page content
    });
});

// instead of the standard way of generating a PDF file
document.GeneratePdf("hello.pdf");

// use the following invocation
document.ShowInPreviewer();

// optionally, you can specify an HTTP port to communicate with the previewer host (default is 12500)
document.ShowInPreviewer(12345);
```

Is it possible for QuestPDF to view PDF before generating the file?

Comment: QuestPDF has a previewer that is installed by GIT separately from QuestPDF.